# Push PowerBI Project in Github to Azure Devops using Github Actions

Tags: git, azure-devops, github-actions

I have been working on a PowerBI Devops Process with the new Workspace Git integration. The issue I am currently having is that the Git integration does not work with our current repository in Github. My solution was to use Github actions to push any updates to a supported Azure DevOps Repo, but when I get the following error:

hint: You have divergent branches and need to specify how to reconcile them.

I am able to run these commands in this order on my local repository and it works, but when I do it in Actions it gives me this error.

name: Push_To_Devops

```
on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v2
      - name: Get Status
        run: git status
      - name: Add Email
        run: git config --global user.email <EMAIL>
      - name: Add Name
        run: git config --global user.name <NAME>
      - name: Add DevOps
        run: git remote add upstream https://${{ secrets.AZURE_DEVOPS_TOKEN }}@dev.azure.com/<ORG>/<PROJECT>/_git/<REPO>
      - name: View Remotes
        run: git remote -v
      - name: Pull Origin
        run: git pull origin main
      - name: Pull Upstream
        run: git pull upstream main
      - name: Push
        run: git push upstream main
```

If I add a --rebase command to the Upstream Pull request it gives me a merge error on the file I am trying to update.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Be sure to add `fetch-depth: 0` to the checkout task.